# quotation marks in string parameter insert statement

Tags: java, sqlite, insert

Hi I've been trying to insert a string into a sqlite database through java. but the string parameter I'm passing in the values sql statement has quotation marks in it as content. I'm thinking that is the error I'm getting why it isn't inserting into the database. is there a way to bypass the quotation marks in the insert statement. thank you.

this is the code:

```
public void addNote(String topicadd, String contentadd) throws Exception
{   
    try
    {
        getConnection();
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("insert into tbl_notes (notes_topic, notes_content) values ('" + topicadd + "', '" + contentadd +"')");
        System.out.println("inserted note");
    }
    catch (Exception m)
    {`enter code here`
        System.out.println("error insert topic");
        System.out.println(m.getMessage());
    }
}
```

this is the parameter kind of long... this is all in contentadd

```
import java.sql.*;

Resultset rset = null; (this has no new ResultSet() initialization)
Connection conn = null; (this has no new initialization too...)
Statement statement = null; (this has now new initialization)

always.....
try
{

}
catch (Exception e)   <- can switch e for any other alphabet
{
     e.getMessage();
    System.out.println("error this module"); <- personal practice
    throw e;
}

- getting connection

Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:m.db");
*** this is sqlite connection format 'm.db' is the database name

establish connection first..
statement syntax follows:
statement = conn.createStatement();
rset = statement.executeQuery("select * from tbl_notes");
- executeQuery is used for SELECT sql statements
rset = statement.executeUpdate("insert into tbl_notes (ID, status) values
('100', 'status here');
```

the whole text is in string contentadd, I'm making a short note-taking program... Well, it doesn't execute the insert statement... error somewhere near (word from text) on command prompt... I'm using sqlite... Please let me know if you need more detail. thank you again.

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: [Use parameterized queries.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: sorry, I posted the codes involved now. thanks.

Comment: @DanD. Please note that the *parameterized queries* are called `PreparedStatement` in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `PreparedStatement` to insert values containing special characters:

```
getConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into tbl_notes (notes_topic, notes_content) values (?, ?)");
statement.setString(1, topicadd);
statement.setString(2, contentadd);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

As you see you can use parameters with a `PreparedStatement` which can contain also quotation marks.

Also you get some protection against SQL injection because the Strings given to a `PreparedStatement` are escaped accordingly.